# Model binding space character to char property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a simple viewmodel with a `char` property...

```
public char Character1 { get; set; }
```

The default model binding doesn't seem to be converting a space character (" ") into this property, resulting in the following ModelState error...

```
The Character1 field is required.
```

The html input element is created in javascript:

```
var input = $('<input type="password" name="Character' + i + '" id="input-' + i + '" data-val="true" data-val-custom maxlength="1"></input>');
```

- There is no `[Required]` attribute on the property.
- The value being posted is definitely " " in model error `AttemptedValue` property.
- `ModelState.IsValid` returns false due to the above error.
- The model property has the null character value of `\0` after binding.

Why is the space character not being bound to the `char` property?

***Update:***

Changing the `char` property to a `string` binds as expected.

Comment: is the whitespace returned to the controller?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the controller action the char property on the model has the null character value (\0).

Comment: can you show relevant code from the view?

Comment: If there's no Required attribute it should not complain

Comment: Updated question with markup sample.

Comment: I believe this is because inherently the textbox is actually storing a value of type string - not a char.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't explain why normal characters bind to the char property as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a failing of the DefaultModelBinder. If you use FormCollection in your action, the string comes back as a space.

This IModelBinder implementation shows how the default model binder is behaving, and gives a possible solution:

```
public class CharModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var dmb = new DefaultModelBinder();
        var result = dmb.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        // ^^ result == null

        var rawValueAsChar = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).ConvertTo(typeof(char));
        // ^^ rawValueAsChar == null

        var rawValueAsString = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawValueAsString))
            return rawValueAsString.ToCharArray()[0];
        return null;
    }
}
```

Register it in your Global.asax with:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(char), new CharModelBinder());
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple, `char` is defined as a value-type (`struct`) while `string` is defined as a reference type (`class`). This means that `char` is non-nullable and must have a value.

That's why the `DefaultModelBinder` (that you're probably using) is automatically sets the validation metadata for this property as `required` even though you didn't add the `[Required]` attribute.

Here's the [source](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/ModelMetadata.cs#L58) for `ModelMetaData.cs` (line 58):

```
_isRequired = !TypeHelpers.TypeAllowsNullValue(modelType);
```

So you end up with the `ModelMetaData.Required` for your `Character1` property set to `true`.

However, you can explicitly configure the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` *not* to automatically set value-types as `required` using the following:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider.addimplicitrequiredattributeforvaluetypes%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but why is an empty space character not considered a valid value? I consider " " to be different to empty string or null. I'm currently inspecting the source to see why it would be treated any differently.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found the offending code in `System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult`:

```
private static object ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
      if (value == null || destinationType.IsInstanceOfType(value))
        return value;
      string str = value as string;
      if (str != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        return (object) null;
      ...
}
```

I'm unsure if this is a bug or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hit this issue in .NET Core recently because the SimpleTypeModelBinder has the same check, so added the following:

```
    using System;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

    public class CharModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(
            ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(char))
            {
                return new CharModelBinder();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }


    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     An <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinder" /> for char.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     Difference here is that we allow for a space as a character which the <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.SimpleTypeModelBinder" /> does not.
    /// </remarks>
    public class CharModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private readonly TypeConverter _charConverter;

        public CharModelBinder()
        {
            this._charConverter =  new CharConverter();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public Task BindModelAsync(
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            {
                // no entry
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            try
            {
                var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
                var model = this._charConverter.ConvertFrom(null, valueProviderResult.Culture, value);
                this.CheckModel(bindingContext, valueProviderResult, model);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var isFormatException = exception is FormatException;
                if (!isFormatException && exception.InnerException != null)
                {
                    // TypeConverter throws System.Exception wrapping the FormatException, so we capture the inner exception.
                    exception = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception.InnerException).SourceException;
                }

                bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, exception, bindingContext.ModelMetadata);

                // Were able to find a converter for the type but conversion failed.
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void CheckModel(
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
            ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult,
            object model)
        {
            // When converting newModel a null value may indicate a failed conversion for an otherwise required model (can't set a ValueType to null).
            // This detects if a null model value is acceptable given the current bindingContext. If not, an error is logged.
            if (model == null && !bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsReferenceOrNullableType)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                    bindingContext.ModelName,
                    bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelBindingMessageProvider.ValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(valueProviderResult.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }
        }
    }
```

And within the Startup:

`serviceCollection.AddMvc(options => { options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CharModelBinderProvider()); })`